# Bar Chart not displaying when using chart.js

Tags: asp.net, bar-chart, chart.js

I am trying to display a bar chart using chart.js.

The data JSON is in another file called barchart.txt from where I am reading it in my function. It looks like the format of data is incorrect because when I put alert on first line of function, even that doesn't work.

Both barchart.txt and Default.aspx are at same location.

> barchart.txt

```
{
       labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
    {
              label: "Dataset Testing",
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    }
       ]
}
```

> Default.aspx

```
<html>
    <canvas id="mybarChart1"></canvas>
</html>

<script>
    $.getJSON("barchart.txt", function (data)
            {
                alert("here");
                var ctx = document.getElementById("mybarChart1");
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: data,
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: I have pasted code of barchart.txt above. I am just learning JSON so I did another example json2.txt in which I wrote some sample data and reading it and it works fine. Similarly if I copy paste JSON from barchart.txt to Default.aspx and save it in variable like var mydata = {whole data here} then it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue solely lies in your *`barchart.txt`* , Obviously, that's not a valid *JSON* object. A proper *JSON* object would look something like, `{"key": "string"}` , you can refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) to learn more about *JSON*.

also, you should probably change your *`barchart`* file's extension from *`.txt`* to *`.json`*

so, the data inside your *`barchart.json`* file should look like this ...

```
{
    "labels": ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    "datasets": [{
        "label": "Dataset Testing",
        "backgroundColor": [
            "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
            "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
            "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
            "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
            "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
            "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)"
        ],
        "borderColor": [
            "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
            "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
            "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
            "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
            "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)"
        ],
        "borderWidth": 1,
        "data": [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json is not valid. You can validate it here http://jsonlint.com/

```
{
"labels": [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July"
],
"datasets": [
    {
        "label": "Dataset Testing",
        "backgroundColor": [
            "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
            "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
            "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
            "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
            "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
            "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)"
        ],
        "borderColor": [
            "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
            "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
            "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
            "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
            "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)"
        ],
        "borderWidth": 1,
        "data": [
            65,
            59,
            80,
            81,
            56,
            55,
            40
        ]
    }
]}
```

Try with the above json